# Why do semaphores have a max value?

Tags: c++, concurrency, language-lawyer, c++20, semaphore

[Semaphores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/semaphore) in C++ take a template parameter equal to the maximum count of the semaphore.

```
template <std::ptrdiff_t max_value>
class counting_semaphore;
```

One precondition of `counting_semaphore::release` ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/release)) is that

```
update + current_counter <= max_value
```

Enforcing this precondition (1) requires a "bounds check" and (2) requires that `counting_semaphore`s with different max values are different classes with different member functions (because `counting_semaphore` is a template class). While the performance costs are low, there don't seem to be any major benefits to having a max value. The user should easily be able to ensure they don't violate this precondition, and if they can't, creating a wrapper class to enforce the precondition would be easy.

Doesn't this violate Zero Cost Abstractions?

Comment: If they didn't have a max value, they wouldn't actually do anything. The point of a semaphore is to only allow X entities access to the resource. If X is infinitely large, you may as well not have the semaphore. Do you mean that they shouldn't have a maximum value as a template parameter?

Comment: Also: "*Enforcing this precondition*" Preconditions are *not* enforced. That's what makes them preconditions. If they are violated, then you get UB.

Comment: @NicolBolas There are two values, a ```max_value``` and a ```current_counter```. In your comment, X is the ```current_counter```, which is all it needs. Sure, the ```current_counter``` could be infinitely large if you call ```counting_semaphore::release(large number)```. Why does the program need to stop me from doing that?

Comment: @NicolBolas "Preconditions are not enforced." In that case, the question is just "why does the class even need to keep track of the maximum value?" If I want to know what the maximum value is, I already knew it at compile time. I don't need to call ```counting_semaphore::max()```.

Comment: @Bobby `max` is helpful three software modules and 100,000 lines of code later when you've ether forgotten the max, abstracted and generalized the code so much that it's impossible to figure out where the semaphore came and how it was defined, or just want to help out the other programmers using your code to write that other module.

Comment: @Bobby: "*In that case, the question is just "why does the class even need to keep track of the maximum value?"*" Well, how else can it keep track of it? If you pass it as a parameter to the constructor, that parameter would have to be stored somewhere. And to define the precondition, you need to reference the value that was used to initialize the object. So... it would have to actually still be around, right? So either it's a member of the object, or it's a compile-time constant associated with the class. IE: a template parameter.

Comment: @Bobby: "*Why does the program need to stop me from doing that?*" It doesn't "stop you". The value defines when your code is functional and when it is not.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. Generally speaking, this should be enforced by the basic logic involved. You obtain the semaphore, and sometime later you release it. You simply need to assure that you only release a semaphore you've obtained

Comment: @user4581301 while that's a fine answer, the main goal of this question is to figure out if there is some peculiarity with the implementation details (such as with Windows/Linux) that required ```max_value```. I thought that maybe this issue was discussed when semaphores were proposed for C++20, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes, that is my point. In most cases, that is how it will work.

Comment: @NicolBolas "how else can it keep track of it?" see Jerry's comment

Comment: @Bobby it's not an answer at all. It's a comment responding to one of your comments. An answer would have been posted below.

Comment: @NicolBolas "If they didn't have a max value, they wouldn't actually do anything" Can you elaborate? When I was taught semaphores, admittedly a _very_ long time ago, the examplar was a work queue, with consistency constraint, semaphore value = size of queue. Adding to the queue increments the semaphore, threads in a thread pool (blocking) decrement the semaphore to pick up work. There was never any mention of max, although, as I said this was a very long time ago :).

Comment: @TooTone: "*semaphore value = size of queue*" Yes, and when you created that queue, you did so with a maximum size. And if someone tried to release it when it hadn't acquired it, then your semaphore would break. The maximum value is there; you just don't *see* it.

Answer (score 4):

> Semaphores in C++ take a template parameter equal to the maximum count of the semaphore.

This is incorrect. They take a template parameter which is a least possible maximum value. `std::counting_semaphore<10>` will be a specialization with `max() >= 10` and which allows you to call release 10 times. The actual maximum `max()` can be larger.

Why might the library care about the maximum value the user intends to use? That might affect the algorithm or representation. On a platform where 64-bit atomics are available but expensive, if you didn't include a maximum value or equivalent in the type, the library has to choose between making all semaphores worse, or not supporting larger semaphores. (zero cost)

> Enforcing this precondition (1) requires a "bounds check"

Preconditions are not checked.

> (2) requires that counting_semaphores with different max values are different classes with different member functions (because counting_semaphore is a template class)

This is a feature, not a bug, as described above.

> (from a comment) It doesn't answer why a semaphore needs to store a max_value.

This is not stored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we need to back up and talk a moment about the basic point of a counted semaphore.

The basic point of a counted semaphore is to assure that a maximum of N threads have access to some resource at any given time. To do that you normally initialize a counter to N. To obtain the semaphore, you block until the counter is greater than 1, then decrement the counter. To release the semaphore, you increment the counter.

Temporarily ignoring minor (okay, crucial) details about things being atomic, the semaphore looks something like this:

```cpp
template <ptr_diff_t max>
class semaphore {
    ptr_diff_t current = max-1;
public:
    void obtain() { this_thread::block_until(current > 1); --current; }
    void release() { ++current; }
};
```

If some code were to release a semaphore it hadn't obtained, that would increment the counter higher than it started. When/if that were to happen, more than N threads could obtain the semaphore, which is exactly what it's supposed to prevent.

So, one way or another, the semaphore needs to know what value to initialize the counter to to start with. That could be passed as a template parameter, or a ctor parameter, but we have to tell it what N is one way or another.

In the interest of minimizing overhead, the semaphore won't generally do much (if anything) to enforce a thread releasing the semaphore only if it actually owns the semaphore at the time. To enforce that, the standard essentially places that as a precondition on the calling code ("don't release a semaphore you don't own")--but there's generally no overhead involved in enforcing it. The semaphore itself will often simply ignore the possibility, because it's allowed to misbehave if you violate the precondition. The calling code will usually enforce it only via logic, such as using a lock type that will obtain the semaphore when it comes into scope, and release it again when it goes out of scope.

Comment: While this does answer the part about enforcing the precondition, it doesn't answer why a semaphore needs to store a ```max_value```.

Comment: @Bobby: It answers why it needs to *have* a max value. It does *not* necessarily need to store it anywhere. Keep in mind that the precondition is a requirement placed on *calling* code, not necessarily something that's done by the semaphore itself (though an implementation could provide a debugging version that did).

Comment: "It does not necessarily need to store it anywhere." That was supposed to be part of the OP (it is part of issue (2)), but upon rereading, the main paragraph over-emphasizes the "enforcing" component of the question. Should I edit the OP or ask a new question?

Comment: To be clear: storing the max value causes 2 inefficiencies, (i) the memory for the max_value and (ii) the instantiation of multiple template classes. The max_value can just be stored in the instructions of the member function ```max```, so (ii) encapsulates (i). This begs the question, why do we need to store the max_value anyway?

Comment: @Bobby: I don't know that either is really necessary. A question leading from a misunderstanding isn't a big deal.

Comment: I think I might have an answer, but I'm not sure. If a template class has a member function that does not reference the template parameters, that member function's code can probably be shared across template instantiations. And if member functions that use the template parameters are never used, then they probably don't appear in the binary.

Comment: "A question leading from a misunderstanding isn't a big deal." What do you mean? What misunderstanding? I'm saying your answer doesn't answer the entirety of the OP.

Comment: @Bobby: I'm saying it does. A semaphore doesn't necessarily need to store the maximum value. A belief to the contrary is simply a misunderstanding. Likewise, enforcing the precondition doesn't necessarily impose any overhead--it's up to the calling code, and normally enforced via the logic, not code adding overhead specifically to enforce it. Enforcement costs are generally nonexistent rather than low. As for merging identical code: yes, it happens--but I don't see where the OP alludes to code duplication, even distantly.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying. I think we are talking past each other. "I don't know that either is really necessary." I interpreted "either" to be in reference to "Should I edit the OP or ask a new question?" and "A question leading from a misunderstanding isn't a big deal." to belittle my question. With "I'm saying it does.", what is "it"?

Comment: "I don't see where the OP alludes to code duplication, even distantly." from OP:"(2) requires that counting_semaphores with different max values are different classes with different member functions (because counting_semaphore is a template class)."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256106/discussion-between-jerry-coffin-and-bobby).